# Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to call an api through `useEffect` until then I have set `loading` true and if I get a `response` or an `error` I set it to false.

But I am getting an error if I try to do so.

Error:

```
 Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

This error is located at:
    in HomeScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
   ...
```

Code:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const { authToken, logInfo, userData } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [token, setToken] = authToken;
  const [isloggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = logInfo;
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = userData;

  if (userInfo) {
    useEffect(() => {
      const isUserCreatedProfile = async (loggedInUserInfo, token) => {
        try {
          const apiHeaders = {
            "User-Agent":
              "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
            Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            token: token,
          };

          await axios
            .get(`${baseUrl}/api/user?email=${loggedInUserInfo["email"]}`, {
              headers: apiHeaders,
            })
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              navigation.replace("CreateProfile", {
                name: loggedInUserInfo["custom:Name"],
                email: loggedInUserInfo["email"],
              });
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };
      setLoading(true);
      isUserCreatedProfile(userInfo, token);
      setLoading(false);
    }, []);
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator color={colors.BorderColor} size="large" />
      ) : (
        <Pressable
          style={{ alignItems: "center", marginTop: 300 }}
          onPress={async () => {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
            console.log(
              "token after delete:",
              await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"),
            );
            setIsLoggedIn(false);
            await Auth.signOut();
            setToken(null);
            setUserInfo(null);
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Logout</Text>
        </Pressable>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Why I am getting this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add useState to followings

```
 const [token, setToken] = useState(authToken);
  const [isloggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(logInfo);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(userData);
```

Move if condition inside the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (userInfo) {
      /// content
   }
}, [userInfo])
```

Comment: Moving If statement inside useEffect worked. Thanks